# How to Add room categories for a particular hotel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, relational-database

I am creating a hotel master where i've these tables :

```
tbl_hotel_type : id,type_name,type_code and more
tbl_hotel : id,name,code and more
tbl_hotel_info : id,hotel_id,hotel_type_id and more
tbl_room_categories : id,hotel_type,room_catname,room_catcode and more
```

Now i want to relate which hotel has which room categories i.e.

1.Should i add another column in "tbl_hotel_info" as "room_categories" that will contain ids of all room categories in single column in particular row of "tbl_hotel_info" for a particulat hotel info.

2. Or should,I create a new column in "tbl_room_categories" as "hotel_ids" that will contain all ids of hotel belongs to this particular room_category row.

Or both approaches are wrong and, I've to do something else please suggest me a better way to achieve this . Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something seems wrong with your design. I am not expecting a `hotel_type` to be in room categories. Where is the `HotelTypes`? (I don't see a reason to prepend table names with `tbl_`.)

In practice, it sounds like you want a junction table. I would envision tables such as:

```
RoomCategories:  RoomCategoryId, CategoryName, CategoryCode, . . .
HotelRoomCategories:  HotelId, RoomCategoryId
Hotels:  HotelId, HotelTypeId
HotelTypes:  HotelTypeId, TypeName, TypeCode
```

I also don't think you need a separate "hotel info" table. That information would seem to belong in the `Hotels` table directly.

Comment: Ok In room_categories table i'll remove column "hotel_type" and i'll create a new table as "HotelRoomCategories" with columns Hotelid and roomcategoryid as you suggested but this means for every hotel i'll insert as many room_categories as admin selected in HotelRoomCategories table or should i create a single entery with comma separated ids of room categories in RoomCategoryId column ?

Comment: i.e. if admin selected 6 room catregories in checkbox for a particular hotel then every time i have to insert 6 enteries with same hotelid but different room categories . But problem is when admin add, edit or delete some enteries then i have to re enter those enteries in "HotelRoomCategories" table or should I create a single entery only with comma separated ids of roomcategories ? If their is a better way can you suggest it will be of great help .